# expected single matching bean but found 3

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, interface

I am trying to reduce duplicate code for DAO layer of my application.
In order to do so I have created one general interface with methods that all of my POJOs use and can extend it.

```
public interface DaoInterface<T extends Object> {


    public void save(T object);

    public List<T> getList();

    public void deleteById(int id);

    public void update(T object);

    public T getById(int id);


}
```

That part works great however I am stuck with another problem. 
I have three classes (among others of course) InvoiceEnergy, InvoiceGas and InvoiceWater that extend the same abstract Invoice class. 
Despite having small differences all three have the same methods when it comes to calling the database.

Instead of having three very similar intefaces:

```
public interface InvoiceEnergyDAO extends DaoInterface<InvoiceEnergy> {

    public InvoiceEnergy getLatest();

    public List<InvoiceEnergy> getInvoicesForCalulation(Invoice invoice);

    public List<InvoiceEnergy> getUnpaidInvoices();

    public InvoiceEnergy getLastResolved();

    public void resolveInvoice(InvoiceEnergy invoice);

    public void unresolveInvoice(int id);

}
```

I have created one:

```
public interface InvoiceDao<I extends Invoice> extends DaoInterface<I> {

    public I getLatest();

    public List<I> getInvoicesForCalulation(Invoice invoice);

    public List<I> getUnpaidInvoices();

    public I getLastResolved();

    public void resolveInvoice(I invoice);

    public void unresolveInvoice(int id); }
```

For which I have three implementations (one is below ):

```
@Repository("invoiceEnergy")
@Transactional
public class InvoiceEnergyDAOImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, InvoiceEnergy> implements InvoiceDao<InvoiceEnergy> {



    @Override
    public InvoiceEnergy getLatest() {
        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(
                "select * from kamienica.invoiceenergy where date = (select MAX(date) from kamienica.invoiceenergy)");
        return (InvoiceEnergy) query.uniqueResult();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<InvoiceEnergy> getInvoicesForCalulation(Invoice invoice) {
        Query query = getSession()
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "select * from kamienica.invoiceenergy where status = :status and date <= :date and baseReading_id is not null order by date asc")
                .addEntity(InvoiceEnergy.class).setParameter("date", invoice.getDate())
                .setParameter("status", PaymentStatus.UNPAID.getPaymentStatus());
        return query.list();

    }

(more code here.....)
```

Everything seems to be fine but when I run the test I get:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'kamienica.dao.InvoiceGasDaoImplTest':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: kamienica.dao.invoice.InvoiceDao
>   kamienica.dao.InvoiceGasDaoImplTest.invDao; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [kamienica.dao.invoice.InvoiceDao] is defined:
>   expected single matching bean but found 3:
>   invoiceEnergy,invoiceGas,invoiceWater

I don't understand what is the problem... I have multiple interfaces that successfully extends DaoInteface yet I get an error while trying to extend it here.

**EDIT 1**

@Dragan
Here is the class. The most strange thing is that the new solution (reducing interfaces) works fine in application and only crashes on tests....

```
public class InvoiceGasDaoImplTest extends EntityDaoImplTest {


    @Autowired 
    InvoiceDao<InvoiceGas> invDao;

    @Test
    public void findById() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(invDao.getById(1));
        Assert.assertNull(invDao.getById(2));
    }

    // @Test
    // public void save() {
    // invDao.save(getSampleMeter());
    // Assert.assertEquals(invDao.getList().size(), 5);
    // }

    // @Test
    // public void deleteById() {
    // invDao.deleteGasByID(5);
    // Assert.assertEquals(invDao.getList().size(), 4);
    // }

    // @Test
    // public void deletetByInvalidId() {
    // invDao.deleteGasByID(9);
    // Assert.assertEquals(invDao.getList().size(), 4);
    // }

    @Test
    public void findAll() {
        Assert.assertEquals(invDao.getList().size(), 1);
    }

    // @Test(expectedExceptions =
    // org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)
    // public void saveDuplicate() {
    // invDao.save(getDuplcateNubmerApartment());
    // Assert.assertEquals(invDao.getList().size(), 4);
    // }

    public MeterGas getSampleMeter() {
        MeterGas meter = new MeterGas();
        meter.setApartment(null);
        meter.setDescription("test");
        meter.setSerialNumber("7676434211");
        meter.setUnit("test");
        return meter;
    }

    // private InvoiceGas getSampleInvoice() {
    // InvoiceGas invoice = new InvoiceGas("fsdfsd", description, date,
    // totalAmount, reading)
    // return null;
    // }

    public MeterGas getDuplcateNubmerApartment() {
        MeterGas meter = new MeterGas();
        meter.setApartment(null);
        meter.setDescription("test");
        meter.setSerialNumber("1");
        meter.setUnit("test");
        return meter;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I have managed to pass the test by adding @Qualifier after each Autowire.
Example:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("invoiceWater")
InvoiceDao<InvoiceWater> invDao;
```

What I don't understand is that I only had to do this in the tests- the program runs just fine on the server without that annotation...

Comment: What is the Spring version you use?

Comment: Please post the relevant autowirings in the class `InvoiceGasDaoImplTest`. Also, did you try with an explicit qualifier, just to be sure that the infrastructure is correctly configured?